# Does the Sachs-Wolfe effect depart from $1/3$ for large $k$?

Tags: cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background

In the Sachs-Wolfe effect (the one at last scattering, not the ISW), the standard result is
$$
\frac{\Delta T}{T} = \left( 1 - \frac{2}{3} \right) \Delta \Phi = \frac{1}{3} \Delta \Phi .
$$
To calculate this in full one might do integrals, but there is a standard simple argument to justify the factor $2/3$ in the first expression, where one says that if $\Delta \Phi$ is positive then local processes are going a little faster than the average so last scattering takes place a little earlier. (Well in fact most of the presentations I have read are rather hand-waving on this point, and I admit I am not doing much better). People often say that $a(t)$ is itself a type of clock, but I will not appeal to that notion. Rather I think one can argue that the local time goes a bit fast, so last scattering takes place a little early, and this is why $a$ is a little smaller than the average in the presence of a positive metric perturbation. This timing difference can be calculated from $dt/d\tau = 1 + \Phi$ leading to a net time shift of
$$
\Delta \tau = - \int_0^{LS} \Delta \Phi \, dt .
$$
For long wavelengths $\Phi$ is constant right through both radiation-dominated and matter-dominated periods under ordinary Big Bang cosmology, so this integral gives $\Delta \tau = \Delta \Phi t$. One
then gets the standard result
$$
\Delta a = \frac{da}{d\tau} \Delta \tau = -\frac{2}{3} \frac{a}{t} \Delta \Phi t = \frac{2}{3} a \Delta \Phi
$$
and hence the famous factor one third.

My question is (1), have I understood this correctly, and if I have, then does it follow that for shorter wavelengths (those for which density perturbations stalled during radiation domination) the result will be different because now $\Delta \Phi$ depends on time in the integral?

And a follow-up (2). Is the $\Delta \Phi$ larger or smaller at earlier times for large $k$? For a sub-Jeans-length wavelength, the density contrast is constant (or oscillating) in the radiation-dominated era, so this suggests $\Delta \Phi$ was falling as $a$ grew, so it started out larger than the value it eventually reached at matter-radiation equality (and hence at last scattering). In this case the integral gives a larger $|\Delta \tau|$ and hence the $2/3$ gets multiplied by a number greater than 1 so the final $\Delta T/T$ gets smaller, or indeed might change sign. Is that right?